# Access point problem

Tags: 14.04, intel-wireless, hot-spot, iwlwifi

```
:~$ sudo iwconfig eth1 mode master
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
    SET failed on device eth1 ; No such device.

:~$ ethtool -i wlan0 | grep driver
driver: iwlwifi

:~$ lspci | grep -i network
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 (rev 35)
```

Answer (score 2):

The driver *iwlwifi* usually creates an interface wlan0, not eth1. Check:

```
ifconfig
```

If you have no wlan0, something else is wrong and we should diagnose and correct it first:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
rfkill list all
```

If there is a wlan0, then the correct sequence is:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode master
```

Please note that not all wireless device and driver combinations can be switched to all modes. Please see: http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi

> AP mode (experimental; only on some devices/firmware versions)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if your ethernet deive id is not eth0?

try **iwconfig** command in terminal to check your ethernet device id.